# stackoverflow markdown editor cursor issue

Tags: javascript, html, markdown

I m using stackoverflow markdown editor but the issue is that the editor launches with the cursor already advanced a few spaces and in code entry mode. the code is

```
          var converter1 = Markdown.getSanitizingConverter();

            converter1.hooks.chain("preBlockGamut", function (text, rbg) {
                return text.replace(/^ {0,3}""" *\n((?:.*?\n)+?) {0,3}""" *$/gm, function (whole, inner) {
                    return "<blockquote>" + rbg(inner) + "</blockquote>\n";
                });
            });

            var editor1 = new Markdown.Editor(converter1);

            editor1.run();
```

why is that happening?

Comment: Are you talking about the built-in editor? Where did you find this code?

Comment: does it matter as to where I found the code?

Comment: If you read the question carefully I have already told that the editor is the one stackoverflow is using

Comment: Ok, does it happen all the time have you tried closing/reopening your browser?

Comment: https://github.com/StackExchange/pagedown/blob/master/demo/browser/demo.html @Ivan

Comment: @ivan yes it is happening all the time